# PHP cURL Returning innacurate information

Tags: php, api, curl, github

I'm doing a simple curl on this address: https://github.com/users/davidhariri/contributions_calendar_data

When i grab the result with this function:

```
function fetch_data($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);
    return $result;
}
```

The strings are correct, but the ints (the contributions) are wrong.

Results from curl

```
[...["2014/01/04",0],["2014/01/05",0],["2014/01/06",0],["2014/01/07",1],["2014/01/08",0]]
```

Results from just navigating to the address

```
[...["2014/01/04",0],["2014/01/05",0],["2014/01/06",1],["2014/01/07",5],["2014/01/08",5]]
```

Something during the curl process might be transforming ints to binary and back again? I have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: Post the results you are getting, and explain why they're not what you expect.

Comment: Just navigating with the browser shows all 0's just like cURL for me..

Comment: Look at the last few values and compare. They aren't the same

Comment: I'm seeing the same results as cURL when navigating to the page.

Comment: Well this is embarrasing. Private repos don't show up as contributions unless you're logged in. So my useragent from my testing server didn't have access to the private data, but when i was testing the url, I was logged in, so I did. Long day. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are not logged in in the browser. You may get different results if so.

Comment: Realized this about 5 minutes ago. D'oh!